# How to get a QByteArray from a QString?

Tags: qt, unicode, encoding, decoding, qstring

I am trying to understand how `QByteArray` and `QString` work together in Qt. I am using Qt 5.9.

I have the following case where I create a `QByteArray` in memory.

```
QByteArray qba;
quint8 version = 1;
qba << version;
quint8 type = 122;
qba << type;

qDebug() << qba.length() << " " << QString(qba);
```

The debug statement prints:

```
2   "\u0001z"
```

So, I have 2 bytes of data and the string representation is extracted.

Now, what I want to do is start with the string representation (which is given to me as a raw C++ char array) and create the `QByteArray` representation. So, I create the array as follows:

```
char msg[] = { '\\', 'u', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'z', '\0' };
QString testStr = QString::fromUtf8(msg);
QByteArray testRaw = testStr.toUtf8();
qDebug() << testRaw.length() << " " << QString(testRaw);
```

Now this prints:

```
7   "\\u0001z"
```

I am not sure how I can start from such a character array and get the byte array representation. I am not sure if this is a string encoding issue but I could not recreate this binary representation regardless of which String method I tried (`fromLatin1`, `fromUtf16` etc.)

Comment: I've posted answer just after your edit. Now I see that your question is not precise. Why do you need this conversion what you need to do with it?

Comment: I need this conversion because I am using a library libdmtx which decodes data matrix images. The decoder returns a `const char *` and I am trying to basically get the binary representation to parse it. I am guessing the returned string is UTF-8 encoded but I am not sure. The documentation from them does not say anything.

At the moment, I am just trying to reproduce how I can go back and forth between QByteArray and const char * given that I know the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion between `QString` and `QByteArray` is encoding depended!
Your `QString(qba)` assumes that data are UTF-8 encoded, see [QString documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-8).

In other direction you have:

- [toLatin1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLatin1)
- [toLocal8Bit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLocal8Bit)
- [toUtf8](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUtf8)

Ans so on, there are also vice versa static methods.

---

Note that `qDebug() << anyString;`
doesn't print data literally but in form for developer, that is why it is surrounded with quotes and unprintable character was converted to "\u0001"

---

```
QByteArray qba;
quint8 version = 1;
qba << version;
quint8 type = 122;
qba << type;

// character '\1' is not printable, so qDebug do a developer friendly conversion 
qDebug() << qba.length() << " " << QString(qba);

// to revert conversion, you code should look like this:
QString convnerted(qba);
QByteArray reverted = convnerted.toUtf8();

Q_ASSERT(reverted == qba);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, yes, the QString(qba) gave me a utf-8 representation, I guess. So, I tried doing the same in memory (in the second part of the code). Why was I not able to recover the QByteArray? I thought the line `QString testStr = QString::fromUtf8(msg);` will give me the same representation.

Comment: which version of Qt? Qt4 has different behavior in this matter.

Comment: Yes, but the converted QByteArray does not have the same length i.e. 2 vs 7. So, something in the representation of the string has gone wrong.

Comment: I am using qt 5.9

Comment: first output: `7   "\\u0001z"` so it is fine, in second output you have pasted a `qDebug` output which performed conversion, so why you are surprised?

Comment: The first output is `2   "\u0001z"`. This is correct as my QByteArray has 2 bytes and the converted string QString(qba).length() is also 2. On the other hand with my try with the hardcoded array, I have the string and the byte array which is of length 7. So, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am passing the same character stream...or so I think

Comment: Yes, since you provided such array, you are not performing a reverse operation so out put is different.

Comment: qDebug() is bad for debugging encoding issues. Better write to a text file or print toHex() of the bytearray, to check the exact bytes.